# $\sum_{i<j}x_i x_j=1$ implies $\sum_{i\ne k}x_i<\sqrt{2}$ for some index $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, contest-math

A friend of mine asked me the following olympiad-style problem, and I couldn't solve it. I post it here to get some hints or advice on it.

---

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ distinct positive real numbers, where $n\geq2$.

Suppose that the sum of products of 2 numbers among them, equals 1. That is; $$\sum_{i<j}x_i x_j=1.$$

Prove that there exist some index $k$ such that $\sum_{i\ne k}x_i<\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose this is not the case, and consider
$$S = \left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 + 2\sum_{i < j} x_ix_j = \sum_i x_i^2 + 2.$$
On the other hand, we can also express $S$ in the following way:
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_k x_k^2 + \sum_k x_k \left( \sum_{i \neq k} x_i\right) \\
&\ge \sum_k x_k^2 + \sqrt{2}\sum_k x_k
\end{align*}
Comparing the two expressions, we obtain
$$\sqrt{2}\sum_k x_k \le 2 \implies \sum_k x_k \le \sqrt{2},$$
which contradicts the assumption.

Answer (score 6):

A direct proof:
$$
\left(\min_k\sum_{i\ne k}x_i\right)^2
< \left(\sum_kx_k\right)\left(\min_k\sum_{i\ne k}x_i\right)
\le \sum_kx_k\sum_{i\ne k}x_i
=2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j=2.
$$
The first inequality is strict since each $x_i$ is positive.